# C# Asp.net - Interact with objects located in DataList using objects outside of the DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

Hi i have a DataList which contains a Label inside and a Button that is outside of the DataList

I'm trying to make the button set a text in the label... Something like this

> label1.text = "bla bla";

but i couldn't find label1

is there any way i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

you cant assign it like this becouse the controls created in the fly so you need to reflect the control to get their properties for example

```
foreach (DataListItem dli in DataList1.Items)
{
    Label Label2 = (Label)dli.FindControl("Label2");

    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + " " + Label2.Text;
}
```

Comment: Okay but what if i want to get the value of a label inside the datalist?

Comment: do the same thing to get the exact label and get the object then use label.text for the object you exactly want , depending on the control name you can get or set the data

Comment: moath, it says Label2 was null. Object reference not set to an instance of an object o.o

Comment: make sure you are using the same Id that you assigned to the controller